# Common eigenvector of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ and $S$ be two symmetric, compact linear operators on a (separable) Hilbert space $H$ that commute. Why is there at least 1 common eigenvector of $T$ and $S$?

Comment: Doesn't the usual proof for commuting transformations work? If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and $W$ is the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$, then for every $w\in W$ $T(Sw) = S(Tw) = \lambda(Sw)$, so $S(W)\subseteq W$; restrict $S$ to $W$ and find an eigenvector for $S|_W$. (Note the common eigenvector may corespond to different eigenvalues).

Comment: @Arturo: of course it does, provided you know that there *are* eigenvectors for either $S$ and $T$; this is guaranteed by (an easy part of) the spectral theorem for symmetric (= self-adjoint) compact operators.

Comment: @t.b.: Well, right; same reason you would want "symmetric" in the finite-dimensional case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two commuting compact operators are *simultaneously diagonalizable*. This means that there exists an orthonormal basis such that both $S$ and $T$ are diagonal with respect to that basis, i.e. every vector in such a basis is a common eigenvector.

Comment: Hi Martin. Do you happen to know if a finite family of commuting compact operators on a **Banach** space has a common eigenvector?